# Symfony 4: Do not redirect to /login for matching routes

Tags: php, symfony, configuration

I have a Symfony Application that has two primary sections.  `/` (everything under root e.g. `/userProfile`) and `/api/` (everything under the `/api` route e.g. `/api/userInfo/3`).

I'm using Twig to render the actual pages under root, and a simple `JsonResponse` to render everything under `/api`.  Currently, when a user tries to access any page / resource when they are not logged in, they are redirected to `/login` and then to the page / resource they requested.

I'd like to alter this behavior for all resources under `/api`.  What I'd like `/api/whatever` to do is either return the requested resource (if logged in), or return a 401 if not logged in.  I'd like to continue to redirect to `/login` for all other routes.

(NOTE:  the `/api` routes are not "RESTful" API routes per ce.  They are "internal" API routes that the UI uses to request data it needs to render the various pages.  So it's safe to assume that a user would have logged in via the normal login form prior to their client requesting one of these routes.)

Here's my `security.yaml`:

```
security:
    providers:
        db_provider:
            id: database_user_provider
    encoders:
        App\Utility\Security\DatabaseUser: bcrypt
    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: unanimous
        allow_if_all_abstain: false
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            context: main
            form_login:
                provider: db_provider
                login_path: login
                check_path: process_login
                default_target_path: manage
                use_referer: true
                failure_handler: App\Utility\Security\AuthenticationFailureHandler
            user_checker: App\Utility\Security\UserChecker
            anonymous: ~
            logout:
                path: logout
                target: login
            access_denied_handler: App\Utility\Security\AccessDeniedHandler  #Turn this off in dev.

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/forgot, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/%app.locales%, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

I've tried adding a new firewall context of `api`:

```
api:
    pattern: ^/api
    context: main

    # If I don't include this (from "main" firewall), I get an error stating no UserAuthenticationListener has been provided for secuirty.firewall.api.
    form_login:
        provider: db_provider
        login_path: login
        check_path: process_login
        use_referer: true
        failure_handler: App\Utility\Security\AuthenticationFailureHandler
```

Symfony complains if I do not include `login_path` and `check_path`.

So, how do I tell Symfony to simply fail and return a 401 when a user is not logged in (or session has expired), when (and only when) they are accessing a route under `/api`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get this working, move the `api` firewall above `main`.

We can then set it up on `security.yaml` with the following structure:

```
api:
  pattern: ^/api
  context: main
  stateless: false
  anonymous: true
  guard:
     authenticators:
        - App\Security\ApiAuthenticator
  provider: db_provider
```

The other thing we need is an implementation of `AuthenticatorInterface`. e.g. the `App\Security\ApiAuthenticator`

We only need to implement the following two methods from the interface:
`start` and `supports`

```
public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
{
    return new Response('', Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
}

public function supports(Request $request)
{
    return false;
}
```

**Note:** The above implementation was tested on Symfony 4 (4.3)

Answer (score 0):

This is how my security is looking. It's working the way you wanted, just that I use OAuth

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    oauth_token:
        pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/token
        security:   false
    oauth_authorize:
        pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/auth
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            check_path: /oauth/v2/auth_login_check
            login_path: /oauth/v2/auth_login
            use_referer: true
    api:
        pattern:    ^/api
        fos_oauth:  true
        stateless:  true
        anonymous:  false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
        guard:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\GoogleAuthenticator
                - App\Security\FacebookAuthenticator
            entry_point: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the path `^/api` with the allowed roles in the access_control section https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#add-code-to-deny-access

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

i would use the @Security annotaion
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html